# Php Highlight Elements Dynamically

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something like this.

I have 10 span elements running through for loop:

```
<?php $counter = 7;?>
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) :?>
     <span class="button <?php echo $counter;?>"><?php echo $i;?></span>
<?php endfor;?>
```

What I need to do is assign class highlite to first 7 elements.

Now counter variable is dynamic and could hold any value from 1-10. The idea is to always highlite the $counter number of items starting from the first one.

Comment: So you need to have a `highlight` class and assign it while `$counter` is `<` 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `if` statement should do the trick

```
<?php $counter = 7;?>
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) :?>
     <span class="button <?php if($i <= $counter) echo 'highlite';?>"><?php echo $i;?></span>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $counter = 7; ?>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
    <span class="button <?php echo ($counter > $i) ? "highlite" : ""; ?>"><?php echo $i;?></span>
<?php endfor; ?>
```